# Rel links not working when using MAMP

Tags: html, server, mamp, broken-links

I've been developing my website using Coda2 and all of the links work perfectly (all images show up, all links work etc etc).

However I have now got MAMP and none of my links work. I think the fundamental issue is that the server doesn't recognise "../" so it can't find any of the other web pages or images!

The structure goes something like this:
   index (folder) ---> everything concerning homepage
   contact (folder) --> contact.html, other stuff on the web page etc etc

The rel link from index page to contact is "../contact/contact.html" which is definitely correct but when I click it, it will say "contact/contact.html" not found which I think means that the "../" part isn't recognised.

Document root is set to the index folder mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.